# SSH: ProxyJump from user without shell

Tags: ssh, openssh, ssh-tunneling

I have a system user `syncoid` as

```
$ cat /etc/passwd
syncoid:x:993:990::/var/lib/syncoid:/run/current-system/sw/bin/nologin
```

with the following ssh config:

```
$ cat /var/lib/syncoid/.ssh/config
Host eve
  User other
  HostName 192.168.10.1
  ProxyJump jumphost
  IdentityFile /var/lib/syncoid/.ssh/eve-syncoid
Host jumphost
  ForwardAgent yes
  User me
  HostName 192.168.1.1
  IdentityFile /var/lib/syncoid/.ssh/eve-syncoid
```

I can connect and login to jumphost with `sudo -u syncoid ssh jumphost`. However, a connection to the server `eve` with `sudo -u syncoid ssh -vvv eve` results in

```
OpenSSH_8.8p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1m  14 Dec 2021
debug1: Reading configuration data /var/lib/syncoid/.ssh/config
debug1: /var/lib/syncoid/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for eve
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 5: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 192.168.10.1 is address
debug1: Setting implicit ProxyCommand from ProxyJump: ssh -vvv -W '[%h]:%p' jumphost
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/var/lib/syncoid/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/var/lib/syncoid/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec ssh -vvv -W '[192.168.10.1]:22' jumphost
debug1: identity file /var/lib/syncoid/.ssh/eve-syncoid type 0
debug1: identity file /var/lib/syncoid/.ssh/eve-syncoid-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.8
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 0: This account is currently not available.
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
Connection closed by UNKNOWN port 65535
```

Do I need a regular user with a shell to perform a ProxyJump?

**Edit:**

- A login to `eve` without ProxyJump over VPN works, so everything is correct with the keys and the config.
- I created a normal user with the same keys/config and there the ProxyJump works.

Comment: Did you solve this? I have literally the same problem, also with syncoid and also with a NixOS client.

Comment: @phry See my answer.

Comment: I found out too. There's a more "correct way" of doing it though - I'll add an answer too :)

Comment: Agreed, I mark yours as solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually not a ProxyJump problem - the service is a hardened systemd service with a limited RootDirectory, so it cannot access the private ssh key.

The folder with the private key has to be added to the `BindReadonlyPaths` following [this github comment](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/pull/98455#issuecomment-1046089745)

```
config.services.syncoid.service.serviceConfig.BindReadOnlyPaths = [ 
  "/var/lib/syncoid/.ssh" 
];
```

Following the comment further this will be solved [by this pull request](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/pull/147559) in the future.

Answer (score 1):

This was actually a problem with the syncoid service definition in NixOS being too restrictive. I had to overwrite

```
systemd.services."syncoid-rpool-user-home" = {
    serviceConfig = {
      ProtectHome = lib.mkForce false;
      StateDirectory = lib.mkForce "";
      RootDirectory = lib.mkForce "";
    };
};
```